# Change size of a line plot, understand how the size argument works

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot, errorbar

I'm making a multiple lines plot with errorbars. If I don't use the `size` argument, everything is fine:

```
# sample data
Response=runif(4)
ResponseMin=Response-Response/5
ResponseMax=Response+Response/5 
Cases=rep(c("Case1","Case2"),each=2)    
df=data.frame(x=1:2,Average=Response,Lower=ResponseMin,Upper=ResponseMax,Case=Cases)
# let's plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=Average,colour=Case)) +
geom_line(aes(group=Case)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Lower,ymax=Upper,width=0.25)) +
labs(y="foo",title="Some plot fu")
```

[image]

However, when I modify the line size, I start getting weird stuff:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=Average,colour=Case)) +
geom_line(aes(group=Case, size = 1)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Lower,ymax=Upper,width=0.25)) +
labs(y="foo",title="Some plot fu")
```

[image]

Why the extra legend entry "1"? And when I add a `size` argument for the errobars, it looks like the size of the lines stays the same, whatever the value of `size` is:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=Average,colour=Case)) +
geom_line(aes(group=Case, size = 1)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Lower,ymax=Upper,width=0.25, size = 1)) +
labs(y="foo",title="Some plot fu")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=Average,colour=Case)) +
geom_line(aes(group=Case, size = 2)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Lower,ymax=Upper,width=0.25, size = 2)) +
labs(y="foo",title="Some plot fu")
```

[image]

Can you help me figure out what's happening here?

Comment: Move size out of your aes mapping like `aes(ymin=Lower,ymax=Upper,width=0.25), size = 2` or add `scale_size_identity()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `size` inside `aes` you are mapping it to a variable

```
`1` = 1
```

and ggplot2 creates a legend. If you just want to set the size, you can do that outside of `aes`:

```
geom_line(aes(group=Case), size = 1)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I clearly have some basic misunderstanding of the `ggplot2`philosophy. Can you point me to (possibly free) resources on this? Not the R help, of course. I need to understand the general paradigm behind the tool, which you don't get by just reading the help files of the various functions.

Comment: I don't know; I learned it by bits and pieces. Maybe the third chapter of [Hadley's thesis](http://had.co.nz/thesis/practical-tools-hadley-wickham.pdf) is a good start? Or you could get his book from the library.

Answer (score 1):

try this, size outside aes()

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=Average,colour=Case)) +
    geom_line(aes(group=Case), size = 1) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Lower,ymax=Upper,width=0.25)) +
    labs(y="foo",title="Some plot fu")
```